# FindObjectOfType - How to write correctly in OnTriggerStay to detect this object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I need to use empty script components as a tags (because in Unity we can only add one Tag to the object, I need more than one). Then, in another Object script, I want to find that 1st object by 'tag' = name of that empty script. So I used FindObjectOfType<>() but don't know how to use it correctly in OnTriggerStay.

```
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other == GameObject.FindObjectOfType<First>())
    {
        CheckPos1 = true;
    }

}
```

Seems like doesn't work, because CheckPos1 doesn't change to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    CheckPos1 = other.GetComponent<First>();
}
```

To understand how it works read this reference:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html

[`GetComponent<>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) looks for the script component exactly in the object you are calling this method on.

[`GameObject.FindObjectOfType<First>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) returns the first object of type `First` from the entire scene, not from the collision, so it wouldn't work for your case if you have more than 1 object with the `First` component. And it's much slower as it searches throughout the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sergey so much. I think I understand it more!
I found solution for my problem, just added Object as a child to my main object and added tag to this object. In my game, in each levels, there will be only 1 object with 'First' tag, then another one 'Second, Third, etc.. up to 7 max I guess. This is puzzle game, and I'm working on checking if you solved puzzle by putting bricks on the correct places :).